# Доступ к файлу во внутренней памяти телефона

Tags: android

есть следующий код

```
mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(
decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + "/slide_3.png", 100, 100));

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String pathName, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);



    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, options);
}
```

во время выполнения возникает ошибка

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/slide_3.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE "/>

Comment: после этого возникает ошибка Error:(11) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character ' '.

Comment: Вы неправильно ввели поле в манифест или неправильно скопировали, попробуйте скопировать и вставить это <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> Я так понимаю ошибка из-за пробела была

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: Господа комментаторы! Вы бы в виде ответа опубликовали) Вам плюсы в репу, сайту - улучшение статистики, всем польза)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Как скажите

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, Поправил ваш ответ, держите плюс в карму)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно ввели поле в манифест или неправильно скопировали, попробуйте скопировать и вставить это

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Я так понимаю ошибка из-за пробела была